# Darle formato a distinto tipo de moneda

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, matlab

Hola buenas estoy realizando un mantenedor cotizacion. Este producto me puede calcular en pesos (CLP) y dolares(USD).
Para estoy tengo una tabla donde muestro el precio unitario y el precio total del producto.
Pero quiero poder que este pueda cambiar de `PESOS a USD` o de `USD a PESOS`

Estoy guardando los valores de los precios unitarios clp y usd en dos input hidden. Desde mi base de datos los precios CLP los tengo del siguiente formato `10000` y los de USD `1000.20`.

Pero en mi tabla me gustaria mostrarlo del siguiente formato  CLP`10.000` y USD `1.000,50`.

**Quiero implementar una function que esta me permita darle formato a los precios y aparte poder cambiar el total de estos con los formatos deseados dependiendo del tipo de moneda**

```js
function change_money(coin){

    switch (coin.value) {
      case 'clp':
      $("#tbl_cotizacion tbody > tr").each(function() {
        var celdas = $(this).find('td');
        var unit = $(this).find('input[name=clp]').val();
        var cant = $(celdas[2]).text();
        $(celdas[1]).text(unit);

        });
        break;
      case 'usd':
      $("#tbl_cotizacion tbody > tr").each(function() {
        var celdas = $(this).find('td');
        var unit = $(this).find('input[name=usd]').val();
        var cant = $(celdas[2]).text();
        $(celdas[1]).text(unit);

        });
        break;
   
      default:

    }
    formart_money();

}

function formart_money(){
  var coin = $("input[name=coin]:checked").val();
  var total = 0;
    switch (coin) {
    case 'clp':
    $("#tbl_cotizacion tbody > tr").each(function(){
       var celdas = $(this).find('td');
       

      unit      = $(celdas[1]).text();
      cant      = $(celdas[2]).text();
      
      unit = unit.split('.').join("");
      
      cant = parseInt(cant) || 0;
      unit = parseInt(unit) || 0;
      
      subtotal = unit * cant
      t_linea = parseInt(subtotal) || 0;
      total  += t_linea;
      $(celdas[3]).text(t_linea);

    });
      break;
    case 'usd':
    $("#tbl_cotizacion tbody > tr").each(function(){
       var celdas = $(this).find('td');

      unit      = $(celdas[1]).text();
      cant      = $(celdas[2]).text();
      
      
      cant = parseInt(cant) || 0;
      unit = parseInt(unit) || 0;
      
      subtotal = unit * cant
      t_linea = parseInt(subtotal) || 0;
      total  += t_linea;
      $(celdas[3]).text(t_linea);

    });
      break;
 
    default:

  }
  alert(total);

}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                          <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="radio radio-danger">
                                <input type="radio" name="coin" id="radio1" value="clp"  onchange="change_money(this)">
                                <label for="radio1">
                                    CLP
                                </label>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                         <div class="col-sm-5">
                           <div class="radio radio-danger">
                               <input type="radio" name="coin" id="radio3" value="usd" onchange="change_money(this)">
                               <label for="radio3">
                                   USD
                               </label>
                           </div>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      
     <table id="tbl_cotizacion" class="table table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr class="table-warning">
                  <th width="5%"># CODE</th>
                  <th width="5%">P UNIT</th>
                  <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
                  <th width="10%">TOTAL</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 001 </td>
                <td> 10.000  <input type='hidden' name='clp'  value="10000"> <input type='hidden' name='usd'  value="50.20"></td>
                <td>  4  </td>
                <td> 40.000  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> 002 </td>
                <td> 100.000 <input type='hidden' name='clp'  value="100000"> <input type='hidden' name='usd'  value="1000.20"></td>
                <td>  1  </td>
                <td> 100.000 </td>
              </tr>
                            <tr>
                <td> 003 </td>
                <td> 20.000.000 <input type='hidden' name='clp'  value="20000000"> <input type='hidden' name='usd'  value="20000.40"></td>
                <td>  2  </td>
                <td> 40.000.000 </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saludos podrias usar **Intl.NumberFormat**

```js
var formatterUSA = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-USA', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
var nuevo_formatoUSA = formatterUSA.format(2500);
alert(nuevo_formatoUSA);
```

En este caso es para Dolares, te dejo la documentacion oficial del mismo para mayor informacion:
[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

Existe una funcion llamada *toLocaleString([locales [, options]])* para darle formato a las monedas, que se utiliza de la siguiente manera

```
console.log(number.toLocaleString('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }))
// → ￥123,457
```

por lo tanto si quieres por ejemplo los dollars

```
number.toLocaleString('en-EN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' })
```

aqui esta la documentacion
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString